# Find data from json/jsonb column by array in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column with json/jsonb data. Database is postgresql.

**column data sample**

```
{"postId": "p522", "groupId": "g11", ...}
{"postId": "p5ds", "groupId": "g234", ...}
{"postId": "p5cz", "groupId": "g597", ...}
```

I am trying to search as an array of data from json/jsonb column.

What's best or right way to do it?

```
SELECT * FROM column_name
WHERE 
-- How i can do, similar to this? 
data #> '{groupId}' IN ('g11', 'g597')

-- this works but only for single. I am trying to find by array. 
meta @> '{"groupId": "g597"}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**

```
SELECT * FROM column_name 
WHERE meta ->> 'groupId' IN ('g11', 'g597')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use operator `?|` if you want something similar to `IN`. It works with `jsonb` type.

```
SELECT * FROM column_name
WHERE meta -> 'groupId' ?| array['g11', 'g597']
```

[More info about json/jsonb operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)